App pool stops with various warnings like 5201, 5009, 5022 Etc. Rapid fail protection set to 5 occurrences, and 6th time app pool stops
we are struggling in finding the root cause for App pool stop at IIS in randomn. Rapid fail protection settings below:

App pool stops after 5 warnings like below: (warning codes are different each time)

Happens only in one webserver out of two from a load balancer.
Most occurrences are during planned recycle times.

The information shared above is not enough to fully understand the situation. Machine access and live debug might be required, so you might open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com to engage Microsoft support.

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 503 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

tried raising microsoft incident, nothing fruitful till now
